# How to query over multiple records in a EAV-like design

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. One with some object like user/person, the other one with extra properties.

I created a demo set to test this. Don't get confused by the data in there. This makes it easy to plug it into your query console.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
    ('object_1'), 
    ('object_2'), 
    ('object_3'),
    ('object_4')) AS objects (id)
) AS o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        ('object_1', 'name', 'john'), 
        ('object_1', 'lastname', 'joans'),
        ('object_2', 'name', 'john'),
        ('object_2', 'lastname', 'johnson'),
        ('object_3', 'name', 'joan'),
        ('object_3', 'lastname', 'johnson')
    ) AS properties (o_id, property, value)
) AS p ON o.id = p.s_id;
```

I would like to find the object that has name 'john' and lastname 'johnson'.
The correct answer is of course 'object_2'
How would I do this?

With the following I get no results (obviously):

```
WHERE 
    (p.property = 'name' AND p.value = 'john') 
AND
    (p.property = 'lastname' AND p.value = 'johnson')
;
```

With the following I get 3 objects,

```
WHERE 
    (p.property = 'name' AND p.value = 'john') 
OR
    (p.property = 'lastname' AND p.value = 'johnson')
;
```

I was thinking in the direction of joining the properties twice. But then you'd have to repeat this trick for every new property.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
    ('object_1'), 
    ('object_2'), 
    ('object_3'),
    ('object_4')) AS objects (id)
) AS o
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
    ('object_1', 'name', 'john'), 
    ('object_1', 'lastname', 'joans'),
    ('object_2', 'name', 'john'),
    ('object_2', 'lastname', 'johnson'),
    ('object_3', 'name', 'joan'),
    ('object_3', 'lastname', 'johnson')
) AS properties (s_id, property, value)
) AS p1 ON o.id = p1.s_id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
    ('object_1', 'name', 'john'), 
    ('object_1', 'lastname', 'joans'),
    ('object_2', 'name', 'john'),
    ('object_2', 'lastname', 'johnson'),
    ('object_3', 'name', 'joan'),
    ('object_3', 'lastname', 'johnson')
) AS properties (s_id, property, value)
) AS p2 ON o.id = p2.s_id
WHERE 
    (p1.property = 'name' AND p1.value = 'john') 
AND
    (p2.property = 'lastname' AND p2.value = 'johnson')
;
```

(yeah ugly duplicated tables, but handy?)

I know the database design is a bit weird, but that comes from the idea that some properties should be extendable. I know this is a pattern.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

I also thought about GROUP BY, HAVING, but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use exists

```
SELECT * 
  FROM objects AS o
 WHERE EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1 
             FROM properties AS p
            WHERE p.property = 'lastname' 
              AND p.value = 'johnson'
              AND o.object = p.object
         )
    AND EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1 
             FROM properties AS p
            WHERE p.property = 'name' 
              AND p.value = 'john'
              AND o.object = p.object
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

The EAV model isn't a pattern - it's an anti-pattern. Pretty much textbook, "Don't design your database like this." If you Google "Bill Karwin antipatterns you should be able to find a full description of why this design is a very bad idea.

You're encountering one of the many reasons why this is the case. Over decades people have gotten enough experience with this to uncover these reasons. There are *very* few situations where it's correct to go against correct DB design and do something like this. Most people who think that they've found that exception are wrong. ;)

With all of that said, if you still want to go down this path you can achieve your goal by joining to the properties once and then doing a COUNT(*) on the number of matches and make sure that it equals the number that you're looking for. For example:

```
SELECT O.object_id
FROM
    My_Objects O
INNER JOIN My_Properties P ON P.object_id = O.object_id AND
    (O.property = 'name' AND O.value = 'John') OR
    (O.property = 'lastname' AND O.value = 'Johnson')
GROUP BY
    O.object_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: 'It is an antipattern' is an (over-generalized) opinion. There are places where EAV is a valid model.

Comment: The fact that it is sometimes the correct approach doesn't make it any less of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `intersect` in this case.

And I prefer the `with` clause to set up test data. (If you already have the `properties` table, then you only need the three last lines here)

```
with
properties as (
  select 'object_1' s_id, 'lastname' property, 'joans'   val union
  select 'object_2'     , 'name'             , 'john'        union
  select 'object_2'     , 'lastname'         , 'johnson'     union
  select 'object_3'     , 'name'             , 'joan'        union
  select 'object_3'     , 'lastname'         , 'johnson'
)
select s_id from properties where property='name'     and val='john'
INTERSECT
select s_id from properties where property='lastname' and val='johnson';
```

Result:

```
object_2
```